# How to rectify the error "Undefined type: user.UserData"

Tags: java, jsp

There is a java beans class **UserData**.

```
package random;

public class UserData {

    String username;
    String email;
    int age;
    public void setUsername( String value )
    {
    username = value;
    }
    public void setEmail( String value )
    {
    email = value;
    }
    public void setAge( int value )
    {
    age = value;
    }
    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }


}
```

And there is a jsp file.

**SaveName.jsp**

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="random.UserData" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/>
    <HTML>
        <BODY>
            <A HREF="NextPage.jsp">Continue</A>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

I keep getting an error saying **Undefined type: user.UserData**.

Any idea how to rectify it?
This has gotten rectified. Thanks to those who helped. 
 HELP FROM HERE.
I have one more doubt. 
In addition to the two above files, there are two more.

**NextPage.jsp**

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="random.UserData" scope="session"/>
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        You entered<BR>
        Name: <%= user.getUsername() %><BR>
        Email: <%= user.getEmail() %><BR>
        Age: <%= user.getAge() %><BR>
    </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

**form.html**

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="SaveName.jsp">
            What's your name? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=username SIZE=20><BR>
            What's your e-mail address? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=email SIZE=20><BR>
            What's your age? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=age SIZE=4>
            <P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT>
        </FORM>
    </BODY> 
</HTML>
```

But when I run this. I do not get any inputted values. Instead. I get this :

You entered
    Name: null
    Email: null
    Age: 0

Any Idea why?

Comment: should it not be `random.UserData` instead of `user.UserData`?

Comment: Yes it should be. Thanks. That part got rectified.

Comment: Someone help me please...

Comment: Help you how? You already accepted an answer for the question.

Comment: That is the answer for the first part. I'm talking about the part after that.

Comment: You should have created a new post or explain the whole thing from the start. Since it's your first post, I answered to the second part in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="random.UserData" scope="session"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified class `class="user.UserData"` in your JSP while you're class is declared as `random.UserData` (package + class name) in Java.

---

***EDIT*** (Second part of your question)

In `SaveName.jsp`, you are actually not saving anything.. You need to set values like this :

```
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="username" value="${param.username}" />
```

Also note that this should be done in a Servlet, not a JSP. JSPs are here to get values and display them, not treat them.

Comment: oh, yes. Thank you for the help.

Comment: So, there is not a single way of doing this using just jsp?

Comment: Di you try what I wrote ? The `jsp:setProperty` should work but it's not the correct way to do it.